# Intellij/Webstorm Yarn - Cannot find Package unless on root

Tags: intellij-idea, yarnpkg

I am trying to add packages via yarn inside of intellij. I can get it to install the package fine, and I can even get it to move the packages to my own custom folder via --modules-folder "ExternalLibs".

The issue I am having is, unless I allow yarn to install on the root and under the node_modules folder, it won't recognize that there is a package.

Is there a way to point the package.json to look in the custom path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try setting `NODE_PATH` environment variable pointing to your folder location in **Node.js** run configuration template: **Run | Edit Configurations...**, expand **Templates** node, select **Node.js** configuration, specify `NODE_PATH` in **Environment variables** field

Please see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-19476#focus=streamItem-27-2819977.0-0

Note that, though the modules in `require()` calls will actually be resolved, you will still see warnings about non-installed packages due to [WEB-25792](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-25792); you have to disable **JavaScript | General | Missing module dependency** inspection to get rid of the warnings

Comment: I've also created a feature request for `--modules-folder` support - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-37902; please feel free to vote for it